# Firebase Google sign in users are not shown error

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase

In Splashscreen I'm checking current user is null or not. And in login activity I have Google sign in button. Login is success. But users are not shown in authentication tab of firebase. Because of this I'm not able to access uid in later activities.

Comment: We need more context on this one, maybe show some code block or more details on how you implemented it.

Comment: This question is very vague. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Since you're using Java, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAuthentication).